# How to show the session id of php with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a web page where in my `index.php` file I run a JS function every so often and this function brings data from a php file called closeuser.php, in this case it is the session id.

Example: if I print the session id directly from the index file, it shows me the session id on the screen or with include and the file name if it shows me what the `closeuser.php` file has, as shown in the following code.

`index.php` file:

```
  <?php 
//session_start();
require_once 'Connections/swag.php';

    $ses = session_id();
    echo $ses;  
    
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon/favicon.ico">
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="font-awesome/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php include("closeuser.php"); ?>
    
    
    
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/utiles.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Closeuser.php file:

```
  <?php

echo "a2";
 $a = session_id();
echo $a;


?>
```

It prints me correctly, but if I do it with a js function, as in the following code, it doesn't show me anything, it shows me an empty string in the console, then I don't know why it's the problem:

```
  $(function() { 
    cron(); // Lanzo cron la primera vez
    function cron() {
         $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "closeuser.php", 
          })
        .done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg)
         
        });
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        cron();
    }, 10000); // cada 10 segundos
});
```

Any idea why you send me the empty string? if I print another string in the `closeuser.php` file, for example `echo "a1";` yes it shows me but the session id doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
@session_start();
```

in `"closeuser.php"`

Comment: You shouldn't add `@` to suppress warnings.

Comment: I already established it, but in fact, even though I did not establish what was mentioned, it works for me locally, that is, it works for me locally but when uploading it to the server, it does not work for me.

Comment: @juliofernandez if it only works local, you probably have a problem with php configuration, make sure your application has permission  in the folder configured for `session.save_path`  and check the whole session configuration.